# IQueryable<T> to raw SQL in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

How can I get the raw SQL generated against the below query in EF 6? I have tried `ToString()`, `ToTraceString()` but those are not working and I don't have access to the `DbContext` object at this point.

```
IQueryable<AccountApplication> query = AppService.QueryService.GetQueryMatching(spec);

var acccounts = (from a in query
                 where a.ApplicationId == applicationId && a.Id != 3
                 select new AccountDto
                            {
                                 Id = a.Id,
                                 Name = a.Account.AccountName,
                                 ApplicationName = a.Application.ApplicationName,
                                 SubsidaryId = a.Account.SubsidaryId.HasValue ? a.Account.SubsidaryId.Value : 0
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Also see [Context Log property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception#context-log-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this

`var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();`